# Calculate nulls for each row plus other condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, conditional-statements

Working in SQL Server.
In reality I have a data of many columns (20+), thousands of rows and multiple data types. I do not have privileges of creating functions or procedures but I can work on temp tables. Here is the simplified snippet of the data.

```
drop table if exists #test
create table #test
(
Id INT,
BusinessName varchar(30),
Address1 varchar(100),
Address2 varchar (100),
Address3 varchar (100),
Postcode varchar (100),
City varchar (100),
Country varchar (20),
Turnover dec(20,2),
domain varchar (100)
)
insert #test values
(1,'A','nr1','street1', 'Court1', null, null, 'GB', 1.1,'www@1'),
(1,'A Ltd','nr1a','avenue1', null, '11968', 'Southampton', 'US', null, 'www@1'),
(1,'A', null, null, 'Court1', null, 'Paris', 'FR', 1.3, 'www@1'),
(2,'B','nr2','street2', null, 'M2 3DW', 'Manchester', 'GB', null, 'www@2'),
(2,'B','nr2a',null, null, 'M2 3DW', 'Manchester', 'GB', 2, 'www@2')
```

For each ID I need to choose record that has the least amount of nulls.

If the least amount of nulls is the same then I need to choose record with Postcode not null,

If still multiple choices, I need to choose one with city not null,

If still multiple choices, I need to chose one with least nulls in all three features (address1, address2, addres3)

Otherwise I can choose top1.

The answer should be:

```
(1,'A Ltd','nr1a','avenue1', null, '11968', 'Southampton', 'US', null, 'www@1'),
(2,'B','nr2','street2', null, 'M2 3DW', 'Manchester', 'GB', null, 'www@2')
```

Here is my attempt on counting the nulls for each row but first of all the address nulls are not added together correctly. Also, I have no idea how to now make the selection based on priorities:

```
Drop table if exists #solution 
select s.*
,case
    when Address1 Is NULL   
    OR Address1 = ''
    THEN 1
End Add1filled
,case
    when Address2 Is NULL   
    OR Address2 = ''
    THEN 1
End Add2filled
,case
    when Address3 Is NULL   
    OR Address3 = ''
    THEN 1
End Add3filled
,case
    when Postcode Is NULL   
    OR Postcode = ''
    THEN 1
End postcodefilled
,case
    when City Is NULL   
    OR City = ''
    THEN 1
End Cityfilled
into #solution
from #test s order by ID

Select
Id,
businessName,
Address1,
Address2,
Address3,
Postcode,
City,
Country,
Turnover,
domain,
sum(Add1filled)+sum(Add2filled)+sum(Add3filled) [Addfilled],
postcodefilled,
Cityfilled
from #solution
group by
Id,
businessName,
Address1,
Address2,
Address3,
Postcode,
City,
Country,
Turnover,
domain,
postcodefilled,
Cityfilled
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Please [edit] and clarifications directly into your questions.

Comment: Is there a primary key?

Comment: the ID column is unique and not null (but its not set as primary key)

Comment: @EllieBiessek, id is not unique in your sample data so it can't be the primary key.

Comment: ah, sorry - It will be unique after making the choice but not before. There is no PK in test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *works* but it's not an obvious solution. "Counting" horizontally, with different data types, isn't simple; you need to unpivot the data and convert them to all the same data type and then `COUNT` the non-`NULL` values. That is what the `APPLY` is doing.

Also, however, in the `APPLY` you need to work out the "priority" of the row,  based on the `NULL` values on 2 rows have the same number of non-`NULL` values. Hence the "highest" priority values have the highest value.

Then, finally, we use the "old" `TOP (1) WITH TIES` method with `ROW_NUMBER` to "filter" to the "first" row in each group:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       T.*
FROM #test T
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(N) AS NotNulls,
                        MAX(P) AS Priority
                 FROM (VALUES(CASE WHEN T.BusinessName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,NULL),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Address1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,CASE WHEN T.Address1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Address2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,CASE WHEN T.Address2 IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Address3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,CASE WHEN T.Address3 IS NOT NULL THEN 3 END),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Postcode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,CASE WHEN T.Postcode IS NOT NULL THEN 4 END),
                             (CASE WHEN T.City IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,CASE WHEN T.City IS NOT NULL THEN 5 END),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Country IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,NULL),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Turnover IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,NULL),
                             (CASE WHEN T.Domain IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,NULL))V(N,P))G
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY G.NotNulls DESC, G.Priority DESC, BusinessName ASC);
```

Comment: Wow! That's amazing Larnu! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The OP's sample data suggests others, @SalmanA .

Comment: Ahh, a case of poor copy and pasting, @SalmanA . Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the first `case`, `count(v.n)` will do the same thing

Comment: No, it won't, @Charlieface, you can't convert the majority of the columns to a `decimal`, so removing the `CASE` would cause a failure.

Comment: Obviously convert the one `decimal` to `varchar` or use a `case` on just that one, rather than having to do it on all the others

Comment: The OP has *other* columns as well though, @Charlieface, according to their question. I therefore think it far better to be explicit and convert them all to the same data type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

use `CASE WHEN` expression to check for `NULL`. Use `row_number()` identify the priortity for each `Id`.

```
with cte as
(
    select  *,
        rn  = row_number() over 
              (
                partition by Id
                    order by nulls, 
                             (case when Postcode is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                             (case when City is not null then 1 else 2 end)
               )
            
    from    #test t 
            cross apply
            (
            select  nulls   = case when BusinessName is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Address1 is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Address2 is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Address3 is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Postcode is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when City is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Country is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when Turnover is null then 1 else 0 end
                            + case when domain is null then 1 else 0 end
            ) n
)
select  *
from    cte 
where   rn  = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there is a primary key. Here is a solution that could be expanded for *n* columns regardless of the datatype:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT Pk
         , Id
         , count_all = COUNT(v)
         , count_postcode = COUNT(CASE WHEN n = 'Postcode' AND v IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
         , count_city = COUNT(CASE WHEN n = 'City' AND v IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
         , count_address = COUNT(CASE WHEN n IN ('Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3') AND v IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
    FROM #test
    CROSS APPLY (values
        ('BusinessName', CASE WHEN BusinessName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Address1',     CASE WHEN Address1     IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Address2',     CASE WHEN Address2     IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Address3',     CASE WHEN Address3     IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Postcode',     CASE WHEN Postcode     IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('City',         CASE WHEN City         IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Country',      CASE WHEN Country      IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Turnover',     CASE WHEN Turnover     IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
        ('Domain',       CASE WHEN Domain       IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) 
    ) AS x(n, v)
    GROUP BY Pk, Id
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte1.*
         , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY count_all DESC, count_postcode DESC, count_city DESC, count_address DESC)
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rn= 1
```

It returns row 2 (has postcode) and 4 (two addresses).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a value to using `apply` for this.  Just use `top (1)` with `order by`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from #test
order by (case when BusinessName is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Address1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Address2 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Address3 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Postcode is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when City is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Country is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Turnover is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when domain is not null then 1 else 0 end
         ) desc,
         (case when Postcode is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (case when City is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (case when Address1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Address2 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
          case when Address3 is not null then 1 else 0 end
         ) desc;
```

All the logic is in one place, and no additional processing beyond the `ORDER BY` is needed.